# Even number of columns on one row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an interesting problem: in Bootstrap, I have a div with a bunch of `font-awesome` icons inside it. My problem is when the browser window is resized, it only puts on of the icons on the next line.

What I need it to do is evenly divide the number of icons displayed. So, for example, if only 4 icons fit on one line, and I have 5, it should display one row of three and one of two. I'm not really sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do something like this

```
div class="icons">
<div class="icon_row_one">
icon icon icon
</div>
<div class="icon_row_two">
icon icon icon
</div>
</div>


@media all and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 300px){
  .icon_row_one {
    display: block;
  }

  .icon_row_two {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

That way it splits up when you want it to but does nothing when it is the correct width.

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of icons is coming from a database and is variable, and the number of icons on each row changes based on the screen width.

Comment: @Jack. What are you using in the backend. Maybe you can set classes in the backend and use this method in the front.

Comment: Sorry, it's an MVC project. I suppose that could work. Let me try that out.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same problem occurs if a box has 3 elements in it. I have two divs with two on one line and one on the next.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the "breaks" are, or at what width one row and 5 columns should break to 2 rows of three and two, you can use a :nth-child selector and set it to clear:left.

More on child selectors  http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col {
        // default styles
    }
    .col:nth-child(3n+4) {clear:left} //break to new line every third column/item, beginning at the fourth item
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
    .col {
        // default styles, for five columns per row
    }
    .col:nth-child(3n+4) {clear:none}
}
```